# TwinColSelectwith single select in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I use Vaadin 7. My question is there any way I can make `TwinColSelect` in Vaadin takes only one value and after that disable for the component the ability to select another item from the list ? and when you remove the selected item you can select another again.

Comment: isn't this bascially a single selection?  setMultiSelect(false) will not help here.  i guess you are better off writing a CustomField instead of forcing the TCS into something it was never designed for.

Answer (score -1):

i am sure you are looking for this:

```
TwinColSelect tw = new TwinColSelect();
tw.setMultiSelect(false);
```

Comment: This prevent from selecting more than one item in the same time. This is not what the question was about.